# Override function AddtoAny open in new window

Tags: hooks

What is the right way to override this function from the [AddToAny](https://www.drupal.org/project/addtoany) module? My aim is to open the AddToAny page in a new page.

I can override it in the original code, but I am not able to create a copy in template.php.

```
$universal_button = sprintf('<a%s href="https://www.addtoany.com/share_save#url=%s&amp;title=%s" **target=_blank**">%s</a>',
  ' class="a2a_dd addtoany_share_save"',
  rawurlencode($link_url),
  rawurlencode($link_name),
  $button_innerHTML
);
```

This is the original function:

```
/**
* Internal function to generate code for AddToAny buttons
*
* @param object $node [optional]
* @param array $values [optional custom url/title values]
* @return
*   String containing HTML code for the buttons
*/
function _addtoany_create_button($node=NULL, $values=NULL) {


  global $_addtoany_num, $base_path;

  $_addtoany_num++;

  $additional_html = variable_get('addtoany_additional_html', '');
  $additional_html_placement = variable_get('addtoany_additional_html_placement', 'before');

  // If $values['url'] is set, use supplied value(s)
  if (is_array($values) && isset($values['url'])) {
    $link_name = (isset($values['title'])) ? $values['title'] : '';
    $link_url  = $values['url'];
  // Otherwise, if $node is set, use best URL/Title
  } elseif (is_object($node)) {
    $link_name  = (module_exists('page_title')) ? page_title_page_get_title() : $node->title;
    $link_url   = url('node/' . $node->nid, array('absolute' => 1));
  // Otherwise, if front page, use best URL/Title for front page
  } elseif (drupal_is_front_page()) {
    $link_name  = (module_exists('page_title')) ? page_title_page_get_title() : variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal');
    $link_url = url('<front>', array('absolute' => 1));
  // Otherwise, use current page's URL/Title
  } else {
    $link_name  = (module_exists('page_title')) ? page_title_page_get_title() : drupal_get_title();
    $link_url = url(current_path(), array('absolute' => 1));
  }

  $javascript = _addtoany_create_script(  $_addtoany_num, $link_name, $link_url);

  $buttons_size = variable_get('addtoany_buttons_size', '16');
  $button_setting = variable_get('addtoany_image', 'share_save_171_16.png|171|16');

  if ($button_setting == "a2a_svg_32") {
    $button_setting     = 'text';
    $button_text        = '';
  }
  elseif ($button_setting == "custom") {
    $button_image       = check_url(variable_get('addtoany_custom_image', ''));
    $button_width       = '';
    $button_height      = '';
  }
  elseif ($button_setting == "none") {
    // Universal share button disabled
  }
  elseif ($button_setting != "text") {
    $button             = explode('|', $button_setting);
    $button_filename    = $button[0];
    $button_width       = ' width="' . $button[1] . '"';
    $button_height  = ' height="' . $button[2] . '"';
    $button_image   = $base_path . drupal_get_path('module', 'addtoany') . '/images/' . $button_filename;
  }

  if ($button_setting != "none") {
    // Permit blank button_text (so AddToAny Kit can set the icon) if set above, or use addtoany_link_text if set
    $button_text = (isset($button_text)) ? $button_text : check_plain(variable_get('addtoany_link_text', ''));
    if (strlen($button_text) > 0)
      $button_text = ' ' . $button_text;

    $button_innerHTML = ($button_setting == "text") ? $button_text : sprintf('<img src="%s"%s%s %s/>%s',
      $button_image,
      $button_width,
      $button_height,
      filter_xss(variable_get('addtoany_image_attributes', 'alt="Share this"'), array()),
      $button_text
    );

    $universal_button = sprintf('<a%s href="https://www.addtoany.com/share_save#url=%s&amp;title=%s">%s</a>',
      ' class="a2a_dd addtoany_share_save"',
      rawurlencode($link_url),
      rawurlencode($link_name),
      $button_innerHTML
    );
  }
  else {
      $universal_button = '';
  }

  // ID is later removed by JS (for AJAX)
  return ( sprintf('<span class="a2a_kit%s a2a_target addtoany_list" id="da2a_%s">
      %s
      %s
      %s
    </span>
    %s',
    ($buttons_size == '32') ? ' a2a_kit_size_32' : '',
      $_addtoany_num,
    ($additional_html_placement == 'before') ? $additional_html : '',
    $universal_button,
    ($additional_html_placement == 'after') ? $additional_html : '',
    $javascript
  ));
}
```